# Fiori Mobile - Hide Launchpad Header

Tags: mobile, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm deploying a mobile app through SAP Cloud Platform Web IDE.

This needs to be deployed to a Fiori Launchpad,  but the problem is the Launchpad Header shows in the app, which is doesn't need to.

How do I disable the header when deploying a Mobile App ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue? Are you using Fiori Launchpad in a browser or are you using a Fiori Client to view the app? If not, are you using Hybrid App Toolkit to build a Cordova app?

Comment: Hybrid App Toolkit to build a Cordova app. This is done from the context menu of the project in SAP WEB IDE.  As part of the process you also have to specify a fiori launchpad to assign it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the app in a standalon or headerless [modes](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/53/7758e0deb0477386ea400c915073b3/frameset.htm).

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/shell-bar/#standalone-mode.

Comment: This app isn't run from the browser, it's a Hybrid (Cordova) app build using Fiori mobile. How do I implement that url in this scenario?

Comment: Have you already checked it in the deployed app and it shows this header?

Comment: Yeah the header shows in the deployed app, unfortunately,

Comment: If it is possible to influence on this header via URL parameter, then there is an API (probably in ushell) which allows to switch on/off this header. Just try to find it (maybe checking of ui5 sources would be required)

Comment: I've tried adding  "appUrl": "#rsamanagecategories-Display&sap-ushell-config=headerless" to the flp-config.json. But still have the header displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/merged-header/.
With Fiori 2.0, the second header should disappear.
Please specify in the manifest:

"config": {
                                           "sapFiori2Adaptation": true
                           },

The Header in the app should be hidden by this configuration.

Comment: I need the Second header, as this page header will be dynamic. It's the first header (the Fiori Header) I need to lose

Comment: Some the guy managed it on this blog... I can't fathom out how though https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/22/make-offline-app-using-sap-cp-mobile-service-for-sap-fiori-part-1/